# Angular Material Drag and Drop - Dragging wrong item when style transform is used

Tags: angular-material, drag-and-drop, css-transforms

I'm using Angular Materials Drag and Drop like in this sample:

```
<div
    cdkDropList
    class="token-list"
    [style.width.px]="50"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <app-token
        cdkDrag
        class="token-block"
        [style.display]="'flex'"
        [style.cursor]="'pointer'"
        [token]="token"
        *ngFor="let token of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
    </app-token>
</div>
```

where app-token is this component:

```
<div
    class="border d-flex justify-content-center"
    [style.height.px]="50"
    [style.width.px]="50"
    [style.border-radius.px]="6"
    [style.margin.px]="1"
    *ngIf="token">
    <div
        class="d-flex align-self-center"
        [innerHTML]="token">
        <!--
            [style.transform]="'scale(3)'"
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

it works perfect and I can precisely drag and sort elements in the list.
Unless I put the commented attribute in the div (just move it two lines up). When I try to pick an element at the bottom border it grabs the next element below instead.

[Pick and drag an item at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzBmy.png)

I tracked it down to being an issue with the style transform but don't know how to work around it.